# jQuery selectable limit

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to add limit of 6 selectable rows but i can't make it work. Any help!!

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $(".selectable").selectable({
      filter: "td.cs",


      stop: function() {
          var result = $("#select-result").empty();
          var result2 = $("#result2");
          $(".ui-selected", this).each(function() {

              var cabbage = this.id + ', ';
              result.append(cabbage);
          });

          var newInputResult = $('#select-result').text();
          newInputResult = newInputResult.substring(0, newInputResult.length - 1);
          result2.val(newInputResult);
      }
  });
 });​
 </script>
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: What behavior are you expecting when the seventh element is attempted? Deselect the first one? Ignore the action? Prompt the user that they have hit their maximum allowed?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `selecting` event callback to do this like following

```
$( "#selectable" ).selectable({
   selecting: function(event, ui) { 
     if ($(".ui-selected, .ui-selecting").length > 6) {
       $(ui.selecting).removeClass("ui-selecting");
     }
   }
});​
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/77KrR/1/)

Reference: [selecting event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/#event-selecting)

Comment: is with this code i was trying to do it but i can't manage to combine the two of the do you have any idea how?

Comment: What do you want to do when user selects more than six elements?

Comment: jsfiddle.net/dw6Hf/28  You can see here what is the problem