# selectable limit stop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to make this selectable script to have selecting limits. I want it to stop selecting when the limit of selection goes over the limit number that is 4.

http://jsfiddle.net/dw6Hf/51/

```
$(function() {
    $(".selectable").selectable({
        filter: "td.cs",

        stop: function() {
            var result = $("#select-result").empty();
            var result2 = $("#result2");
            $('.ui-selecting:gt(31)').removeClass("ui-selecting");

        //    alert($(".ui-selected").length);
            $('#divmsg').html($(".ui-selected").length*2+ " box selected")
            if ($(".ui-selected").length > 4) {
                //alert("Selection of only 4 allowed");
                $('#divmsg').html($('#divmsg').html() + ", Selection of only 4 allowed");
                $(".ui-selected").each(function(i, e) {                  
                    if (i > 3) {

                        $(this).removeClass("ui-selected");
                    }
                });
                return;
            }

            $(".ui-selected", this).each(function() {
                var cabbage = this.id + ', ';
                result.append(cabbage);
            });

            var newInputResult = $('#select-result').text();
            newInputResult = newInputResult.substring(0, newInputResult.length - 1);
            result2.val(newInputResult);
        }
    });
});​
```

thank you

Comment: why is there a `length*2` surely that would output twice the selection?

Comment: i was trying some things!! The thing that i want is to stop selecting boxes after selecting 4 that the limit. do you have any idea how to do it?

Comment: i am new to this, i manage to do most what i need with this script. can you show my on a fiddle hot to add it

Answer (score 0):

Ok now that i understand the requirements this one should give you what you asked for. Changing from stop to selectable means you can decide before it is "selected" not after which is when stop is fired.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dw6Hf/56/)

Comment: My question was: is it possible to stop selecting boxes when i choose more tham 4?

Comment: Ok I thought you simply wanted to remove it after the fact, my mistake i edited my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
$( "#selectable" ).selectable({
    selecting: function(event, ui) {
         if ($(".ui-selected, .ui-selecting").length > 4) {
           $(ui.selecting).removeClass("ui-selecting");
         }
    }       
});
```

duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10817129/jquery-selectable-limit)

**EDIT**
something like this?

```
$(function() {
    $(".selectable").selectable({
        filter: "td.cs",

        // do not allow selecting more than four items
        selecting: function(event, ui) {
             if ($(".ui-selected, .ui-selecting").length > 4) {
               $(ui.selecting).removeClass("ui-selecting");
             }
        }               

        // do whatever you like with the selected
        stop: function() {
            var result = $("#select-result").empty();
            var result2 = $("#result2");            

            $('#divmsg').html($(".ui-selected").length*2+ " box selected")

            $(".ui-selected", this).each(function() {
                var cabbage = this.id + ', ';
                result.append(cabbage);
            });

            var newInputResult = $('#select-result').text();
            newInputResult = newInputResult.substring(0, newInputResult.length - 1);
            result2.val(newInputResult);
        }
    });
});?
```

Comment: i've seen that before but i can manage to add it in the script and make it work! can you help me out

Comment: added EDIT with specific script

Comment: if what I wrote doesn't help, please describe the problem further